# Where does Windows Explorer store the ordering of file item menus, like Start & Quick Launch?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

In the Favorites menu for example, Windows Explorer allows the user to move files and folders around within each sub-menu, and "remembers" the ordering. Where is that ordering information stored?

The Quick Launch Bar and Desktop Toolbars are also examples of this menu-ordering feature.

Answer (score 3):

For Favorites:

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Menu Order\Favorites\Order

For the Start menu:

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Menu Order\Start Menu\Order and 
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Menu Order\Start Menu 2\Order (one contains the ordering for the stuff installed under All Users, the other for your current user)

For the toolbars (e.g., Quick Launch): haven't figured that one out yet.

Answer (score 1):

The directory is here:

**C:\Documents and Settings\Your Name Folder\Application 
Data\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch**

Once it's there, you will have to set the order or emplacement on the bar by yourself.

Comment: Yes, this is the directory of files whose names will appear in the Quick Launch menu, and I know how to drag-and-drop, etc. My question has to do with where the resulting display order information is stored in the system.

Comment: Let me check in the registry... I'll get back to you

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.winxptutor.com/wsaremove.htm